# Expectation of logarithmic of a Laplace random varible

Tags: integration, lower-bounds

Say $Y$ is a random variable with Laplace distribution with zero mean and variance parameter $b$. I am trying to compute the expectation of $\ln(Y+\alpha)$ ($\alpha>0$), that is: $$\int^{\infty}_{0}\frac{1}{2b}exp(-\frac{y}{b})\ln(y+\alpha)dy+\int^{0}_{-\alpha}\frac{1}{2b}exp(\frac{y}{b})\ln(y+\alpha)dy.$$
It seems difficult to obtain an exact form. I am at least hoping for a lower bound. Note by Jensen's inequality the upper bound is $\ln(\alpha)$.

Comment: Please edit typos in your question.

Comment: You are not computing the expectation of $\ln(Y+\alpha)$ but of $\ln(Y+\alpha)\mathbb{I}(Y>-\alpha)$.

Answer (score 1):

The closed form can be obtained with Maple 18.02 by

> with(Statistics): Y := RandomVariable(Laplace(0, b)):
>   Mean(ln(Y+alpha));

$$
1/2\, \left( {\it Ei} \left( 1,{\frac {\alpha}{b}} \right) {{\rm e}^{2
\,{\frac {\alpha}{b}}}}+2\,\ln  \left( \alpha \right) {{\rm e}^{{
\frac {\alpha}{b}}}}+{\it Ei} \left( 1,-{\frac {\alpha}{b}} \right) 
 \right) {{\rm e}^{-{\frac {\alpha}{b}}}},
 $$
where the exponential integral $Ei$ is described [here](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=Ei).